# Encrypt Web.config Using aspnet_regiis.exe

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, security, connection-string

We are developing our first website by asp.net mvc. You know every asp.net project has "web.config" file that Contains sensitive configuration parametersو like connectionStrings (username and password for connecting to database).
Now, for improving security of our web site and avoid hacking, we want to encode or encrypt the content of web.config file. We followed according to 
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/877258/How-to-Encrypt-Web-config-Using-aspnet-regiis-exe. 
At localhost, web.config is encoded as well and loading web site is ok. but when we uploaded our site on the server, The site was loaded with this error:
"An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine."

What is the problem? May you help me?
Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

You missed the following point.

> This method depends on the machine where you originally encrypted the
>   data, for example if machine A encrypts “hello world”, only machine A
>   has the right keys to decrypt it. This result in a non-suitable
>   solution when working with web farms.

You need to encrypt your config file in the server it self. You can't copy a config file which has been encrypted somewhere else (some other machine). Encryption & Decryption is specific to the machine.

Comment: Thank you so much,
but how can I encrypt config file at the server??

Comment: Same way you can do.. using regiis

Comment: As you mentioned that you encrypted the file locally using aspnet_regiis.exe. Same approach needs to be followed on the server. First you copy the config file in plain text to the server, once copied, use aspnet_regiis.exe to encrypt it.

Comment: actually this should be done by the person who is responsible for deployment. He will have access. Otherwise you need to implement your own custom encryption and decryption logic.

Comment: Oh, your right. But we use a hosting provider that provides for us, not a dedicated host.

Comment: In other words, how can i encrypt config file at the server remotely?

Comment: Hello, Where are you? please come here... :)

Comment: If you don't have access to your server for running the aspnet_regiis.exe tool, in that case you do encryption and decryption though code. You can find lot of examples over net for how to encrypt and decrypt using .NET